# show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu^*(\sum_{k=1}^n A_k) = \mu^*(\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k)$ for outer measure $\mu^*$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be a pre-measure on a ring $\mathcal R\subset\mathcal
> > P(\Omega)$ and $\mu^*$ the outer-measure induced by $\mu$ on $\mathcal
> > P(\Omega)$. Show that for sets $A_1,A_2,...\in\mathcal R$ with
>   $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ ($i\neq j$) the following holds:
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu^*(\sum_{k=1}^n A_k) = \mu^*(\sum_{k=1}^\infty
>  A_k)$$

I think since $\mu^*|_\mathcal R = \mu$ I only have to show that this holds for $\mu$, but I don't really know how to start with this. My guess is that you have to find a sequence $(B_n)\subset\mathcal R$ such that $B_1\subset B_2\subset ...$ and use the continuity from below of $\mu$.
Can anyone give me a hint or two? Thanks.

Comment: So I tried using a sequence $(B_n)\subset \mathcal R$ with $B_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n A_k$. Then we have $B_n\uparrow \sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k$. Because $\mu|_{\mathcal R}=\mu$ we have $\mu^*(B_n)=\mu(B_n)$. Let $C_n:=\bigcap_{m=n}^\infty B_m$. Then $B_n\subset C_n$ and hence $\mu^*(B_n)\leq \mu^*(C_n)=\mu(C_n)\leq \mu(B_n)=\mu^*(B_n)$ and we obtain $\mu^*(B_n)=\mu(C_n)$. We also get $\mu^*(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n)\leq \mu^*(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n)=\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(C_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu^*(B_n)$ by continuity from below.

Comment: And so we get $\mu^*(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n)\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu^*(B_n)$. We also have $\mu^*(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n)\geq \mu^*(B_n)$ for all $n$ and so we get $\mu^*(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n)\geq\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu^*(B_n)$. These observations combined lead us to $\mu^*(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu^*(B_n)$ and since $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ and $B_n=\sum_{k=1}^n A_k$ we get our proposition.

Comment: Can I argue like this?